# Docker container existing on `docker-compose up` from RUN apache reload

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml and a Dockerfile, but on `docker-compose up` it's exiting when it gets to the `service apache2 reload`.

Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM php:7.2.1-apache

# Run apt update and install some dependancies needed for docker-php-ext
RUN apt update && apt install -y libpng-dev libicu-dev zip unzip libxml2-dev sendmail

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli gd intl zip xmlrpc soap opcache

# Reload apache
RUN service apache2 reload
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: ./docker/php-apache
        # image: moodle:php:7.2.1-apache
        # volumes:
        #   - ./public_html:/var/www/html
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        links:
            - "mariadb"

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.2.33
        volumes:
            - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            TZ: "Europe/Rome"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
            MYSQL_USER: "moodle"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "moodle"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "moodle"

volumes:
    mariadb:
```

Below is what is output

```
$ docker-compose up
...
Step 5/5 : RUN service apache2 reload
Reloading Apache httpd web server: apache2 failed!
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c service apache2 reload' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

See my container is exited, and stopped.

However, if I run `docker-compose up` with the `# service apache2 reload` line commented out, then run the reload command from within the built container, everything looks OK.

How do I reload apache from the Dockerfile without it exiting?

Comment: I guess there is a configuration error, otherwise would `service apache reload` return 0. I also think it would make more sense to move the command to the entrypoint.

Comment: How do I "move the comment to the entry point"?

Comment: It is a total non-sense to reload apache during the image build phase. You get an error because it is not running and even if it was, it would stop right after the command has been executed for your layer. It is not your container that exists but your image that fails to build in this case (your container does not even try to start). Simply drop that line. Your container will start from the freshly built image with the latest configuration from the image or your mounted config file or whatever config source your have put in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely delete that line from your Dockerfile.

A Docker image only contains a filesystem and some associated metadata.  It doesn't contain any running processes; there aren't "services", and there's nothing you can "restart" from the context of a Dockerfile.

A container typically only runs a single process.  In most cases you'd specify what this is using a `CMD` directive, and it would run some single command as a foreground process.  Commands like `service` or `systemctl` mostly don't work in Docker at all, and aren't necessary: if you need to restart the main container process, you just delete and recreate the container.  In the specific case of the `php:...-apache` [Docker Hub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), this is [provided in the base image `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/14a53e7cbf88bd59af72d086418844a3e0b4160a/7.4/buster/apache/Dockerfile#L282); so when you `docker run` the image, it will start a new Apache server in a clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change
`RUN service apache2 reload`
to
`CMD service apache2 restart`

You must not run services in the image build, they must be run when a container is started. **CMD** executes when user starts the container. If you use RUN a service while build then it would get stuck or fail.